# Receive image from c# in php

Tags: c#, php

I use this code to send an image from desktop application to a php file on server:

```
// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/img.php");
// Set the Method property of the request to POST.
request.Method = "POST"; 
// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
string postData = "hello";
byte[] byteArray = ImageToByte(image);//Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
// Get the request stream.
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
// Write the data to the request stream.
dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
// Close the Stream object.
dataStream.Close ();
// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
// Clean up the streams.
reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

What function should I use in php to receive the image file?

Comment: You're setting byteArray to Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello) prior to writing it to the request stream. I assume that is only for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not forming standartized post, you'll need to read directly from php input.

```
file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided your C# code produces a valid post request, you should be able to fetch it from the global `$_POST` array in PHP.

Comment: _POST only contains parameters send as name=value pairs. Though the ContentType is set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded there is no name=... part in the request and the value isn't properly encoded.